# Trying to get a better understanding of ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

If you take a look at my small code snippet below, what I'm trying to do should be pretty obvious....not every record has *this* field, so on the ones that don't I want to hide it and the label.  What I have here did not work.

```
        <table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1" ng-repeat="agent in vm.agents | orderBy: 'id'" border="0">
        <tbody class="row-hover">
            <tr class="row-1 odd">
                <td class="column-1"><a href="http://larosacre.com/?page_id=1121"><img src="images\{{agent.image}}" alt="" class="aligncenter size-thumbnail wp-image-1116" data-recalc-dims="1" /></a></td>
                <td class="column-2">
                    {{agent.name}}<br />
                    Phone: {{agent.phone}}<br />
                    <p ng-if="{{agent.email}} != ''">E-Mail: {{agent.email}}</p><br />
                    {{agent.bio}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How should I approach this?

Thanks,

newbie

Comment: If you're simply hiding parts of the UI, you can use `ngShow/ngHide`. Using `ngIf` in this context costs too much, since, it reattaches and removes DOM whenever the `ngIf` expression results to true or false. Another caveat in using `ngIf` is it creates a child scope, you're already using `ng-repeat` which creates a child scope, so the cost of creating more scopes doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is given to the **ngIf** directive **will be interpreted** already, by being evaluated within the current **scope**. That is, you do **not** need to (in fact, you actually **have not to**) use the `{{...}}` marker here.

That is, simply using:

```
<p ng-if="agent.email != ''">E-Mail: {{agent.email}}</p>
```

... would do wonders. Although, since, when `agent.email != ''`, then basically, `agent.email` is *truth-y*, being only evaluated to `false` in a **boolean context** if it is `undefined` or empty (or 0, but I believe that won't happen in your case).

What I'm trying to say is, simply use:

```
<p ng-if="agent.email">E-Mail: {{agent.email}}</p>
```

... and you're good to go!

Comment: @LakmalCaldera Hmm, it does **not** with when you simply use `ng-if={{agent.email}}`. See this JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/ha5jyzws/